# ASP.NET FindControl memory leak

Tags: asp.net, memory-leaks

we have discover recently that our ASP.NET application has a lot of lines like this:

```
Label lbXXX = (Label)FormView.FindControl("lbXXX");
```

same for `TextBox`, `Panel`, `Image`, `DropDownList`...

Could this be the reason of a memory leak?

Is as bad as I think?

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** likely to be causing a memroy leak.

To find the cause of a memory leak you should be using a [memory](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) [profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and find out what is holding on to references that it shouldn't be.

The most common reason for memory leaks in .NET is event handlers that have not been unregistered, though this tends to not be a problem in ASP.NET due to its request per thread model.

If you suspect a memory leak (how have you determined that you do have one?), profile in order to find the reason - don't assume.

Comment: Do you have a reference for: _"a common reason for memory leaks in .NET is event handlers that have not been unregistered"_? Is it also true for `ASP.NET`?
 Since everything is going to be disposed at the end of a page's life-cycle, i'm suprised to hear that event-handlers could cause it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I explicitly exclude `asp.net` from this in my answer. You are quite right - the page life-cycle means this tends not to be a problem (though one could still do silly things with static classes).

Comment: @Oded, we think we have a memory leak because our memory usage grows up every day, and we have installed the same app in 30 domains in the same server. Don't you think not disposing those controls could cause a memory leak?

Comment: @MikeJohnson - How do you _know_ that these controls are the issue? Have you profiled the application to see _what_ is holding onto resources?

Comment: we were just guessing..we don't know what is. We are desperate with this. We are now trying to use ANTS, but we have to figure out how it works

Comment: No, we don't know, I was just guessing. We are trying to use ANTS to see what is going on.

Comment: What about MemoryStream, we see we have an old class to crypt strings. MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); but we don't dispose that. Almost all pages call that class.

Comment: @MikeJohnson - Can't tell without seeing how it is used. But if it is part of the page life-cycle, not likely. You need to profile, not guess.

Answer (score 0):

Memory  leaks, impossible here. yeah excessive use of find control  is not recommended. Since you observing lot of such incidents then better  resolve them and clean your code. Performance  is also hitting currently due find control.

Comment: Ok, if we have to access to controls inside FormView how can we do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that it causes memory issues. However, it doesn't come without cost.

As you can see below, the first action is `EnsureChildControls` which calls [`CreateChildControls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx) if they are not created yet. That might cause your performance/memory issue.

> Called by the ASP.NET page framework to notify server controls that
>   use composition-based implementation to create any child controls they
>   contain in preparation for posting back or rendering.

Then not `FindControl` would have this issue but your custom control(s).

This is the implementation (from ILSpy):

```
protected virtual Control FindControl(string id, int pathOffset)
{
    this.EnsureChildControls();
    if (!this.flags[128])
    {
        Control namingContainer = this.NamingContainer;
        if (namingContainer != null)
        {
            return namingContainer.FindControl(id, pathOffset);
        }
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.HasControls())
        {
            this.EnsureOccasionalFields();
            if (this._occasionalFields.NamedControls == null)
            {
                this.EnsureNamedControlsTable();
            }
        }
        if (this._occasionalFields == null || this._occasionalFields.NamedControls == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        char[] anyOf = new char[]
        {
            '$',
            ':'
        };
        int num = id.IndexOfAny(anyOf, pathOffset);
        string key;
        if (num == -1)
        {
            key = id.Substring(pathOffset);
            return this._occasionalFields.NamedControls[key] as Control;
        }
        key = id.Substring(pathOffset, num - pathOffset);
        Control control = this._occasionalFields.NamedControls[key] as Control;
        if (control == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return control.FindControl(id, num + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand very well what you are telling me. WHen we create those controls, we are trying to acceess the info of a control inside a FormView. What we don't do right now is dispose those controls, which I thought could be one of the reasons of our problem.

Comment: If you don't use any custom controls and you're just using `FindControl("DropDownList1")`, there's most likely another reason for the memory leak. You don't need to dipose controls manually since they will be disposed at the end of the page's life-cycle.